# Twitter default widget, links, negative seo and latest Google Webmaster Central latest blog post: "a reminder about widget links"

Tags: seo, google, links, twitter, widgets

With [the latest post from Google Webmaster Central](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2016/09/a-reminder-about-widget-links.html) we're reminded about the quality of non-editorially established links and the rel attribute of the link ideally needing to be nofollow.

For my current team I was asked to feature a Twitter widget prominently above the fold/scroll with our tweet interactions. But without the ability to control the rel attributes of the tweets (some do use `rel="nofollow"` some don't, as you might expect) I'm now curious as to whether this is now seen as problematic, rather than being seen indifferently.

My instinct is that this is directly targeting pages that add those endless boxes of click-bait under an article's footer and that for 'super' widgets like Twitter, which are not link hiding/stuffing/swapping or doing anything too artificial this wouldn't be a concern, not least because as [articles like this](http://wojdylosocialmedia.com/twitter-tweets-get-indexed-google-affect-seo/) point out Twitter is almost a non-event for inorganic SEO.

Comment: That blog post is warning that the links will likely hurt the site they point to.   The one that distributes the widget.   You don't need to worry about it when putting a widget on your own site.

Comment: Gah (can't upvote yet, so forgive me for saying...) thank you! Suddenly that makes **much** more sense